# What is your feedback/experience with the new Stack Overflow setup?

Tags: discussion, database, hardware

It has been one month now that the new hardware for Stack Overflow database is up and running. ([New Hardware for Stack Overflow Database](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/new-hardware-for-stack-overflow-database/))

This setup is a really interesting case (SSD in RAID for a database for a web application).

What is your feedback, observation, advices, etc?

Are the benefits of the increased IOPS only for the hardware part (less servers) or do you see opportunities for the software part (simplifing the architecture of the application through removing caching level, adding new functions that were requesting too many IO for HDs)?

HDs were the bottleneck. Do you see new ones (maybe some applications were not built with really high IOPS in mind)?